# asp.net identity 2.2.1 token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, token, fiddler

Trying to get token from asp.net identity 2.2.1 with this fiddler

[image: fiddler post]

```
grant_type=password&username=test@test.com&password=Tt@123
```

[image: response]

```
error=invalid_client
```

I am keep getting 400 response status code, was working in previous versions, not it doesn't, how can I obtain token ?

Comment: Perhaps the error is what is says: invalid client. If the code didn't change, check the configuration. Does the user exist and are you sure you are using the correct password?

Comment: yes, i re checked it and the username and password are correct and in the database !

Comment: If you want others to help add more information to the question. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask